# Android location update every minute

Tags: android, timer, location

I am currently writing an application that receives location data every minute (or other specified amount of time) and thes send it to server.

The problem that I have noticed is:
When I use my application connected to power source it works perfectly - sends updates with defined interval.
When I use it on battery it sends updates randomly.

For my application I use timer to specify interval of update. This timer runs in Background service. I request updates in timer and remove updates when I receive location.
Fragment of my code:

```
    private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0); 
        }
    } 

    private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            date = date.getInstance(); //used to set time of update.

            if(!GPSupdating)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, locationListenerGPS);
                GPSupdating = true;
            }
        }
    };
```

My location listener:

```
    LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() 
    {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location updatedLocation) 
        {
            myGPSLocation = updatedLocation;
            haveLocationGPS = true;
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGPS);
            GPSupdating = false;
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
```

Do you have any idea why this is not working correctly?

Comment: I had same issues with `"TIMER"` running in background **"service"**
till today i did'nt got any reasoning behind that... SO I used `Alram Manager` in place of `Timer` and that workd perfectly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please send me some sample code where you used Alarm Manager instead of Timer? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good solution - enable/disable listener on each minute.

Better to try following things:

1) Set minimal update time (in requestLocationUpdates ) to one minute and send data to server in update listener:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 60*1000, 0, locationListenerGPS);
```

If you need more accurate update intervals, than:

2) Start separate thread and enable GPS updates on it. Store last location in thread or service variable. Also start timer and on timer tick send location to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Criteria to manage the power. Set power requirement to POWER_LOW. You will loose some accuracy though.

```
LocationManager locationManager= (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
            provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not save energy by enabling and disabling GPS once per minute. Either choose a greater intervall (5 minute) or get the location evry second.
Then store the location in a `lastValidLocation` filed, start your own Timer, and once a minute read out `lastValidLocation`. and send to server if changed.